# object destructuring not working in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure

I have a simple function that's running in an Azure webjob and contains a statement where I'm using ES2016 destructuring. When the function runs, I see the following error:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Here's my function:

```
// Formats an address object into a string
formatAddress(address) {

    if (address) {
        const { street, city, state, zipcode } = address;
        return `${street} ${city}, ${state} ${zipcode}`;
    }
}
```

I'm running my Azure Website on Node 6.3.0.

Removing the destructuring fixes the issue. Running this locally on my own machine (OS X), everything works as expected with the destructuring.

Is destructuring not available on the Windows version of Node or do I have to enable a flag?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
  //package.json
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.3.x"
  }

# iisnode.yml
debuggingEnabled: false
loggingEnabled: true
nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\node.exe" --use_strict // points to node 6.3.1 binary
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you set the Node.js version on Azure Web Apps?

Please try to go to the Azure protal (https://ms.portal.azure.com), and change the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to `6.3.0` in the `Application settings` section. After the modification, it works fine on my side.

[image]

## update

Here is my entire test project on Azure Web Apps, the directory structure is:

```
app.js
iisnode.yml
package.json
web.config
```

The content of each file is also simple:

`app.js`:

```
var http = require("http");

var address = {street : "street", city : "city", state:"state", zipcode:"zipcode"};
const { street, city, state, zipcode } = address;
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  response.write(`${street} ${city}, ${state} ${zipcode}`);
  response.end();
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 1337);
```

`iisnode.yml`:

```
debuggingEnabled: false
loggingEnabled: true
```

`package.json`:

```
{   
    "engines": {
        "node": "6.3.x"
      }
}
```

`web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
          <webSocket enabled="false" />
          <handlers>
               <!-- Indicates that the app.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
               <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
          </handlers>
          <rewrite>
               <rules>
                    <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
                    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">                    
                        <match url="^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                    </rule>

                    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
                    <rule name="StaticContent">
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
                    </rule>

                    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
                    <rule name="DynamicContent">
                         <conditions>
                              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                         </conditions>
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
                    </rule>
               </rules>
          </rewrite>

          <!-- bin directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
          <security>
               <requestFiltering>
                    <hiddenSegments>
                         <remove segment="bin"/>
                    </hiddenSegments>
               </requestFiltering>
          </security>

          <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
          <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
          <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js" debuggingEnabled="false" />
     </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And there is only one Applition Settings: `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` is `6.3.0`.
The test project works fine on my side. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` file to define the engine version and keep the same with `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION`? Or do you have configured a `iisnode.yml` for some specific configurations?

Comment: Please try to remove the `nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\node.exe" --use_strict` in `iisnode.yml`. After removing it, it works fine on my side.

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue is still there even after removing the file completely and stopping and starting the application.

Comment: As i have posted my entire test project as the update. It's strange, because it works fine on my side. Do you have any other configurations but we have ignored?